# Qt retrieve additional data created during request when QNetworkAccessManager finished

Tags: c++, qt

I would like to create an HTTP request and retrieve in the response some variables create during the request.

However, QNetworkAccessManager reponse is asynchronous and use SIGNAL/SLOT functionality, so variable are no more accessible.

Here is an example :

```
void makeRequest()
{
    manager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);

    connect(manager, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)),
            this, SLOT(replyFinished(QNetworkReply*)));
         
    // here is the datas I want to get in the reply
    // objectdata and objectdata2 are created just before the http request
    MyClass objectdata("randomseed");
    MyClass2 objectdata("randomseed") ;
            
    QUrl websiteurl = objectdata.getUrl();

    manager->get(QNetworkRequest(websiteurl));
}


void replyFinished (QNetworkReply *reply)
{
    if(reply->error())
    {
        qDebug() << "ERROR!";
        qDebug() << reply->errorString();
    }
    else
    { 
        QByteArray dataHttp = reply->readAll();
        // How can I get here objectdata and objectdata2 ?
        // I would like to do something like that this->dataSuccess(objectdata,objectdata2,dataHttp);
    }

    reply->deleteLater();
}
```

In a synchronous system this problematic doesn't exist.
Is there a workaround to this problematic ?

Comment: Well, store the additional data in the member variables of your class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it is to capture the locals in a lambda instead of using a separate function for the slot.

```
void makeRequest()
{
    manager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);

    // here is the datas I want to get in the reply
    // objectdata and objectdata2 are created just before the http request
    MyClass objectdata("randomseed");
    MyClass2 objectdata("randomseed") ;

    connect(manager, &QNetworkAccessManager::finished, [this, objectdata, objectdata2](QNetworkReply *reply)
    {
        if(reply->error())
        {
            qDebug() << "ERROR!";
            qDebug() << reply->errorString();
        }
        else
        { 
            QByteArray dataHttp = reply->readAll();
            dataSuccess(objectdata,objectdata2,dataHttp);
        }

        reply->deleteLater();
    }         
            
    QUrl websiteurl = objectdata.getUrl();

    manager->get(QNetworkRequest(websiteurl));
}
```

Another way is to add extra parameters as an attribute in the `QNetworkRequest`.

```
    // Save off the data in the request
    QNetworkRequest req(websiteurl);
    req.setAttribute(QNetworkRequest::User, QVariant::fromValue<MyClass>(objectdata));
    req.setAttribute(QNetworkRequest::User + 1, QVariant::fromValue<MyClass2>(objectdata2));
    manager->get(req);

...
    // Retrieve the data from the reply
    auto data1 = reply->request().attribute(QNetworkRequest::User).value<MyClass>();
    auto data2 = reply->request().attribute(QNetworkRequest::User + 1).value<MyClass2>();
```